# sprintf is not printing the last entry

Tags: c

sprintf is not giving the proper value for tthe variable stats->info.transferID ,but 
printf is giving proper values for that variable ,all the other values are proper

```
char buff[200]; 
sprintf(buff,"Index:1:%u:%u:%d\n",
            stats->connection.peer,
            stats->connection.local,
            stats->info.transferID);
printf("  %s",buff);
printf("  %d\n",stats->info.transferID);
```

info is a structure of Transfer_Info type.

```
typedef struct Transfer_Info {
    void *reserved_delay;
    int transferID;
    ----
    ----
 }
```

the output I'm getting:

```
Index:1:2005729282:3623921856:0

3
```

size of buffer is much enough to hold its value ,

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is not enough information here.  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Please show at least what's stored into `buff` and the `stats`/`info` struct

Comment: please specify size of buff

Comment: You should always prefer `snprintf` over `sprintf` to avoid hard-to-catch buffer overrun bugs. Like if your `buff` is char[] array with size known at compile time, use `snprintf(buff, sizeof buff, ....)`

Comment: i have tried snprintf also ,still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct connection
{
  unsigned peer, local;
};

struct info
{
  int transferID;
};

struct stats
{
  struct connection connection;
  struct info info;
};

int main(void)
{
  char buff[100];

  struct stats s = { { 1, 2 }, { 3 } };
  struct stats* stats = &s;

  sprintf(buff,"Index:1:%u:%u:%d\n",
              stats->connection.peer,
              stats->connection.local,
              stats->info.transferID);

  printf("  %s",buff);
  printf("  %d\n",stats->info.transferID);

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/TL7E4B)):

```
  Index:1:1:2:3
  3
```

Are you sure the buffer is big enough? Are you sure you are using correct type specifiers (`%u` and `%d`)?

Comment: It is just what I wrote 6 min ago. The only possibility, that `buff` is too small to hold all printed info.

Comment: first two %u are for printing ip address and next %d is supposed to print the iperf id which is integer

Comment: What are the types of `peer` and `local`? Are they `unsigned int`? If they are, the bug must be somewhere else, not here.

Comment: peer and local are address of structures ,if i use sepatrate spritf for both structures its working ,

Comment: There's no such thing as an address in C. There are integers, pointers, structures, unions and arrays. What are the types? If they are pointers, you should print them as pointers using `%p` (e.g. `printf("%p\n", (void*)stats->connection.peer)`).